# Invalid user or password or the account is blocked due to multiple failed login attempts

Tags: authentication, passwords, openproject

Error Message:- Invalid user or password or the account is blocked due to multiple failed login attempts. If so, it will be unblocked automatically in a short time.

I have installed Openproject in Ubuntu environment.
Today morning i updated the Openproject.
When i tried to login using my user name and password I got the above error message
The database is Postgresql.
I could able to login to db.
what is the solution to resolve this issue and i am want to unblock the account.
All the accounts, including admin account could not able to login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new username and password with admin rights in postgresql DB.
Grant admin rights to the user.
Login to the website using the new username and password.
GO to adminstration - Authentication - 
check 
AUTOMATED USER BLOCKING
Block user after this number of failed login attempts
--Give the input Zero - 0 
It will allow the user to login any number of times if they fail.
thanks